# How to find malicious unicode with eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Unicode in javascript provides a lot of opportunities for malicious developers to insert backdoors or intentional bugs that are easy to slip passed a code-review, a trivial example:

```js
const user = {
  isNormalUser: true,
};
if (!user.isNοrmalUser) {
  console.log("do bad stuff");
}
```

will print "do bad stuff". Is there a good way to detect this, preferably with `eslint`?

Comment: Interesting... what's the trick here?

Comment: What does the example code have to do with malicious Unicode?

Comment: @Phix  "isNormalUser" !== "isNοrmalUser", one of them contains a bit of deceptive unicode to throw off a human reader

Comment: In the `if` is really `user.isN%u03BFrmalUser`

Comment: Tricky tricky! Reminds me of the "prank" of swapping all semicolons to the [greek question mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/037e/index.htm).

Comment: Don't allow undefined variables maybe

Comment: @MihailFeraru the variable `user` is defined, though. And since this is JavaScript, you cannot verify properties. You need Flow or TypeScript or something to make sure that you're using a known property from the interface.

Comment: A note - the developer doesn't even need to be malicious. This is incredibly easy to mess up by accident. I once spent half an hour trying to find out why code that was `const a = 42; console.log(а)` (only the value is different) didn't work. Turns out it had a Cyrillic `a` because it was typed by accident. You can also introduce the same type of error without non-English characters: `circle = { color: "red" }; if (circle.colour === "red"` - American vs British spelling. Or even just misspelling: `array.lenght`.